# Filter array to have unique values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to filter out my array to contain only unique values.
this is my array data

```
["X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11"]
```

expected result should be

```
["X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row11", "X_row8", "X_row9"]
```

How should i continue my code to get proper result.

```
newArray = [];
for(n in data){
  if(!newArray.indexOf(n)){
     newArray.push(n);
  }
}
console.log(newArray);
```

If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide. thank you

Comment: `["X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11"].filter(function(v,i,arr){ return i==arr.indexOf(v); })`

Comment: Please double-check your expected output - why isn't `X_row9` included?

Comment: using loop:
var x = ["X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10"];

let itm =[];

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  let element = x[i];
  if(i === x.indexOf(element)) {
    itm.push(element)
  }
}

console.log("item", itm);

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to filter out elements of an array based on the return value of a callback function. The callback function runs for every element of the original array.

The logic for the callback function here is that if the `indexOf` value for current item is same as the index, it means the element has been encountered first time, so it can be considered unique. If not, it means the element has been encountered already, so should be discarded now.

```js
var arr = ["X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11"];

var filteredArray = arr.filter(function(item, pos){
  return arr.indexOf(item)== pos; 
});

console.log( filteredArray );
```

**Caveat:** As pointed out by [rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373655/rob) in the comments, this method should be avoided with very large arrays as it runs in `O(N^2)`.

**UPDATE (16 Nov 2017)**

If you can rely on [ES6 features](http://es6-features.org), then you can use [Set object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to create a unique array from a given array, as already specified in @Travis Heeter's answer below:

```
var uniqueArray = [...new Set(array)]
```

Comment: The original ES5 solution is O(N^2) so make sure your arrays aren't too big if you're using that.

Answer (score 41):

As of June 15, 2015 you may use [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to create a unique array:

```
var uniqueArray = [...new Set(array)]
```

---

For your Example:

```
var data = ["X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11"]
var newArray = [...new Set(data)]
console.log(newArray)

>> ["X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11"]
```

Answer (score 16):

Filtering an array to contain unique values can be achieved using the JavaScript **Set** and **Array.from** method, as shown below:

`Array.from(new Set(arrayOfNonUniqueValues));`

**[Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)**

> The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether
>   primitive values or object references.
>
> **Return value** A new Set object.

**[Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)**

> The Array.from() method creates a new Array instance from an
>   array-like or iterable object.
>
> **Return value** A new Array instance.

**Example Code:**

```js
const array = ["X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11"]

const uniqueArray = Array.from(new Set(array));

console.log("uniqueArray: ", uniqueArray);
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use a hash table for look up and filter all not included values.

```js
var data = ["X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11"],
    unique = data.filter(function (a) {
        return !this[a] && (this[a] = true);
    }, Object.create(null));

console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
arr = ["I", "do", "love", "JavaScript", "and", "I", "also", "do", "love", "Java"];

uniqueArr = [... new Set(arr)];

// or

reallyUniqueArr = arr.filter((item, pos, ar) => ar.indexOf(item) === pos)

console.log(`${uniqueArr}\n${reallyUniqueArr}`)
```

Comment: Please provide context to the code

Answer (score 7):

```
Array.prototype.unique = function () {
  return [...new Set(this)]
}
```

then we can write:

```
const arr = [1, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5]
const uniqueArr = arr.unique()
```

Comment: Nice concise solution, it works great! When I try as `Array.prototype.unique = () => [...new Set(this)];`, I get `"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))"`. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Because `this` refer to `window` when you use arrow function, but refer to the array when you use normal function.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```js
var rawData = ["X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11"];

var unique = new Map();
rawData.forEach(d => unique.set(d, d));
var uniqueItems = [...unique.keys()];

console.log(uniqueItems);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reduce` to loop the array and get the not duplicate values. Also uses an aux `object` to get the count of added values.

```js
var aux = {};

var newArray = ["X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11", "X_row7", "X_row4", "X_row6", "X_row10", "X_row8", "X_row9", "X_row11"].reduce((tot, curr)=>{
  if(!aux[curr]){
    aux[curr] = 1;
    tot.push(curr);
  }
  return tot;
}, []);

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is for `es2015` and above as far as I know. There are 'cleaner' options with `ES6` but this a great way to do it (with `TypeScript`).

```js
let values: any[] = [];
const distinct = (value: any, index: any, self: any) => {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
};
values = values.filter(distinct);
```

Answer (score 3):

A slight variation on the `indexOf` method, if you need to filter multiple arrays:

```
function unique(item, index, array) {
    return array.indexOf(item) == index;
}
```

Use as such:

```
arr.filter(unique);
```

Answer (score 2):

I've always used:

```
unique = (arr) => arr.filter((item, i, s) => s.lastIndexOf(item) == i);
```

But recently I had to get unique values for:

```
["1", 1, "2", 2, "3", 3]
```

And my old standby didn't cut it, so I came up with this:

```
uunique = (arr) => Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...arr.map(a=>({[a]:true}))));
```