# How can i filter a big Array of Arrays for a unique value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an Array of 241 items, which have many properties, and one of them, i need to check for duplicates and if they exist i want to retrieve them

```
[{
0: { archived: false,
     codes: ["8051827900013"]},
1: { archived: false
     codes: ["8051827900013", "8052333451"]}
}]
```

i tried to map the array to retrieve only the codes but then how does i filter for duplicates?

sorry for such a newbie question around here.

Comment: this is not a valid syntax `[0: "8051827900013"]`

Comment: If you already map array to get values, you can use answers from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38206915/filter-out-array-to-have-only-unique-values to filter out duplicated values

Comment: what information do you want to retrieve, Could you please tell me your intended results?Thanks